# InflateException when adding toolbar in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am new to material design and i am trying a few things out.
For my app minimum sdk is 21. But my app crashes with the following code.

code for toolbar is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



</LinearLayout>
```

main activity's code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sagar.moviesuccesspredictor.MainActivity">
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="45dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
      android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my java code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar=(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

i do not need any backwards compatibility pre Lolipop.
also i could not find any tutorial without the backward support.
Any help will be great for me.

logcat is

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sagar.moviesuccesspredictor/com.example.sagar.moviesuccesspredictor.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #9: You must specify a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID"
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3320) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: You must specify a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID" />
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.example.sagar.moviesuccesspredictor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: You must specify a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID" />
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:923)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:843)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at com.example.sagar.moviesuccesspredictor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1822) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: show error log .

Comment: where is your stacktrace?

Comment: it does not show any error

Comment: 05/05 18:03:41: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.sagar.moviesuccesspredictor/com.example.sagar.moviesuccesspredictor.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Connecting to com.example.sagar.moviesuccesspredictor
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'

Comment: Are you using compatibility style?

Comment: i added a breakpoint in setcontentview and after that the app crashes without any errors

Comment: no i have a single style file

Comment: Where is your style file?

Comment: <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
      </style>

</resources>

Comment: Check style.xml if your style extends AppCompact style for example:  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: i can extend that but doing so also crashes the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your toolbar id is `toolbar` not `tool_bar`. Use like,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

  }
}
```

**EDIT 1 : Example to use Toolbar**

> toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

> main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/this_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/this_toolbar"
    android:text="TextView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView m_toolbar_title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    m_toolbar_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    m_toolbar_title.setText("Activity Title");

    }

}
```

Your `layout="@layout/toolbar"` in **activity_main.xml**,  `toolbar` should be file_name which is having `<Toolbar>`

Have a look. This may helps you.

Comment: thanks for noticing that. but my app is still crashing after fixing that

Comment: try my edited answer. as per my knowledge 'setSupportActionBar' not required at this stage

Comment: still no luck   with this

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: You must specify a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID" />

Comment: thank you very much. finally it works. youre a real life saver

Comment: You are Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Your toolbar.xml should be like this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: still crashing.

Comment: check the id carefully and theme also

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and add these lines in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>        add this in style and,

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>   apply that theme to your activity like this

Comment: including above answer.

Answer (score 0):

change your main activity xml to this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sagar.moviesuccesspredictor.MainActivity">
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="45dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
      android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the problem was in  tag instead of android:layout , you have to use layout:yourLayoutfile. and make sure you use support toolbar in mainActivity as well

Answer (score 0):

Open `logcat`, it may suggest that Toolbar conflicts with existent ActionBar. Solution is modify AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".ToolbarActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Add theme which has no default ActionBar.